# Can not use parameter in generic class, because is not convertible to base class, although all constraints seem to be good

Tags: c#

I have a Repository class, which looks like this:

```
public class AppUserRepository : BaseRepositoryViewAsync<AppDbContext, AppUser, DTO.AppUsers.AppUser>, IAppUserRepository
{
    public AppUserRepository(AppDbContext dbContext, IBaseMapper<AppUser, DTO.AppUsers.AppUser> mapper) : base(dbContext, mapper)
    {
    }
}
```

The implementation of BaseRepositoryViewAsync looks like this:

```
public class BaseRepositoryViewAsync<TDbContext, TEntityIn, TEntityOut> :
    BaseRepositoryViewAsync<TDbContext, TEntityIn, TEntityOut, Guid>, IBaseRepositoryViewAsync<TEntityOut> 
    where TDbContext : BaseDbContext<BaseUser<Guid>, Guid> 
    where TEntityIn : class, IDomainEntityId
    where TEntityOut : class, IDomainEntityId
{
    public BaseRepositoryViewAsync(TDbContext dbContext, IBaseMapper<TEntityIn, TEntityOut> mapper) : base(dbContext, mapper)
    {
    }
}
```

Well there we can see, that the requirement for TDbContext is, that it is a BaseDbContext<BaseUser, Guid>

The AppDbContext:

```
public class AppDbContext : BaseDbContext<AppUser, Guid>
{
}
```

And the AppUser:

```
public class AppUser: BaseUser<Guid>, IDomainEntityId
{
}
```

The error that I get:

```
AppUserRepository.cs(8, 18): [CS0311] The type 'DAL.App.EF.AppDbContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TDbContext' in the generic type or method 'BaseRepositoryViewAsync<TDbContext, TEntityIn, TEntityOut>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DAL.App.EF.AppDbContext' to 'Base.DAL.EF.BaseDbContext<Base.Domain.Identity.BaseUser<System.Guid>, System.Guid>'.
```

From the error I understand, that the AppDbContext does not fit the requirements of being a BaseDbContext, but I can not figure out why it does not fit, since the AppDbContext directly Extends it.

It seems to me, that everything is implemented correctly, but I also might be wrong.

The not so liked fix is here:

```
public class AppDbContext : BaseDbContext<BaseUser<Guid>, Guid>
{
    public new DbSet<AppUser> Users { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

I don't like this, because then I must override the users dbSet and
this will create a discriminator column in the db, which is not necessary, since all users will be AppUsers.

Comment: A `BaseDbContext<BaseUser<Guid>, Guid>` is a different type of object to a `BaseDbContext<AppUser, Guid>`. I would suggest you go read all about [covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify, this will not compile:

```
BaseDbContext<BaseUser<Guid>, Guid>> x = new AppDbContext();
```

Even though `AppDbContext` inherits from `BaseDbContext<AppUser, Guid>`, and `AppUser` inherits `BaseUser<Guid>`.

The reason is [covariance and contravariance in generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance). It's easiest to explain with supposing that it's possible and see what can go wrong.

In this case, suppose assignment above works and you have something like this in base context:

```
public class BaseDbContext<TUser, IID>
{
    public DbSet<TUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Now, for `AppDbContext` this is `DbSet<AppUser>`, but if I was able to assign `AppDbContext` to `BaseDbContext<BaseUser<Guid>, Guid>>` - that would mean I can now add *any* `BaseUser<Guid>` to that `DbSet`, not just `AppUser`. I could add some other user which inherits from `BaseUser<Guid>` but is NOT `AppUser`. For reasons like this such assignment is not allowed.